# What if the two Higgs doublet model is proved right?

Tags: particle-physics, field-theory, higgs, gauge

Two higgs doublet model predicts five higgs bosons. If five higgs will be found then how it will impact the known physics?

Comment: You have asked other variations on this topic before and this one seems far too broad.  It's not reasonable (IMO) to ask how all of physics would change if any particular theory was confirmed (or refuted for that matter).

Comment: Pretty sure "TWO HIGGS DOUBLET MODEL" wasn't an acronym for anything, so I removed the unnecessary capitalization.

Comment: Smells like you have a mock thesis underway and you are drag netting info.

Comment: The popular [review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0034).

Answer (score 1):

It would have minimal impact on *known* physics. If the predictions of this model did not agree with the predictions of the Standard Model for already-observed physics, it would already have been falsified!

Comment: A spot-on comment. But only a comment, not an answer in the OP's or, frankly, anyone's reckoning, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos The OP specifically asked “how it will impact the known physics?” and I feel that I accurately answered that question.

Comment: Yes, if more Higgses are found, the known physics will already be impacted: upended. Some, but, evidently, not all, might read the question to ask for further, unexplored, handles on new physics extending known such.

Comment: And that expansive reading is exactly the one that has resulted in five members voting to close the question as too broad, including you and me. Only the narrow, literal interpretation is suitable for an answer.